# Block Sign Up and allow only Login when using universal login on the Auth0 Android SDK?

Tags: android, auth0

I am trying to use the Auth0 Android SDK for my android app to provide authentication for users. However, I do not want users to be able to sign up on the android app but only allow login. This is possible to do when using the Lock widget on Auth0 but could not find a way to achieve this when using Universal Login.

This is how I am initializing Universal Login:

```
WebAuthProvider.login(account)
                .withScheme("demo")
                .withAudience(String.format("https://%s/userinfo", getString(R.string.com_auth0_domain)))
                .withScope("openid profile email read:current_user update:current_user_metadata")
                .withParameters(mapOf(Pair("prompt", "login")))
                .start(this, object: AuthCallback {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal Login leverages Lock or Auth0.js so by default you should be able to disable sign up as you mentioned above.

Here is a quote from one of the senior support engineers on the subject.

> You can indeed configure Lock to not show the sign up option
>   (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#allowsignup-boolean-
>   8), however, have in mind that this would purely an interface thing so
>   technically sign ups would still be possible (for example, a technical
>   user could call the sign up API directly).
>
> In other words, depending on your exact scenario and related
>   requirements there’s more to it than just disabling the option in the
>   interface. For example, for a database connection you would need to
>   use the disable sign ups toggle in the connection settings itself in
>   order to disable public sign ups completely.